# Integrate $\int \frac{14x}{(9+x^2)^3}dx$ using u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Section 5.2:
Can somebody Verify this solution for me?

Integrate $\int \frac{14x}{(9+x^2)^3}dx$ using u-substitution

---

Let $u=9+x^2$. Then $\frac{du}{dx}=2x$ and so $\frac{du}{2x}=dx$. Making these substitutions we get:

$\int \frac{14x}{(9+x^2)^3}dx$

$= \int \frac{14x}{u^3}\frac{du}{2x}$

$= \int \frac{7}{u^3}du$

$=7 \int u^{-3}du$

$=7 \frac{u^{-2}}{-2} + C$

$=\frac{-7}{2} (9+x^2)^{-2} + C$

Comment: Have you tried to differentiate last line? A good way to make your own validation.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: You can check your solution by integrating your last step and by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%2814x%29%2F%289%2Bx%5E2%29%5E3).

Comment: This is for my students during the corona shut down >.<